# Content Assist Does Not Work with New V31.0 IDE

Tags: ide

I have a new windows 7 PC.  I performed a completely vanilla installation of JRE 7, Kepler, and the latest (31) version of the Force.com IDE.  It works fine except for:

Content Assist simply does not work.  No suggestions come up under any circumstances.

I have been using the Force.com IDE for 6 years and know it well.  This is a new bug for me.  Content Assist was always a little spotty, but it never shut down completely and permanently.

This is a huge pain.  Any bright ideas? help!

Thanks.

Comment: The new version is a complete rewrite. And content assist is missing. Looks like they rushed the version out the door. The syntax parser also has bugs (I've filed one already), but do feel free to log bugs on GitHub and they'll track it.

Comment: The bug list is at https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues. Having looked at the code a bit, in my view it is more of a mild rework to start to use the tooling API and do compilation locally than a complete rewrite. For my project work, I'm staying on an earlier version for now.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going with Keith's suggestion for now. Go back to V30.0. I realize it's not the best way to handle the situation but at least you get your auto complete / assist feature (hence the productivity) back which is a big deal for any software person. Make sure to have "Show only the latest versions of available software" unchecked in Eclipse installation process in order to see 30.0