# Auto Complete for Force.com IDE plugin in Eclipse

Tags: ide, eclipse

Hi I cannot find the Auto Complete plugin for Salesforce IDE which I have installed in Eclipse. Version: Kepler Service Release 2

Comment: Since someone commented on Mavensmate/Sublime Text as an alternative, I'll also mention that in the next week or so I'll be releasing a new tool for Force.com development, [Illuminated Cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/), a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA that includes extensive code completion as well as many other features. It's not freeware or open source but will be available for a **very** competitive price and includes a free 30-day evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it might be coming soon according to the idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrptAAC).

> Josh Kaplan
> The developer console now has autocompletion for Apex code, in addition to its long tradition of autocomplete for Visualforce.  Can I get a huzzah from the crowd?
>
> We will add this to the IDE plugin as part of our refactoring to utilize the Tooling API in the coming year.

It looks like there is a visualforce plug in [here](https://github.com/ajayhada/Rich-VisualForce-Editor), but haven't tried it out.

Something else I haven't tried but it looks like auto-complete is part of the beta install, [Changes in Force.com IDE Beta Version 34.0.0.20150511](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/wiki/Changes-in-Force.com-IDE-Beta-Version-34.0.0.20150511#invoke-auto-completion-of-system-namespaces-types-and-members) and [Downloading the Beta Version of the Force.com IDE](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/wiki/Downloading-the-Beta-Version-of-the-Force.com-IDE).

Comment: Hi Jenny,
Tried the Rich VisualForce Editor plugin that you are talking about but it gives an error.

Comment: @ZarqIqbal updated my answer, it looks like the beta version has that capability now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jenny. That worked for me! I just hope that they bring the auto complete for VF tags soon too!

Answer (score 0):

It's been broken for quite a while now ([link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46157/content-assist-does-not-work-with-new-v31-0-ide))

Personally, I use Mavensmate with Sublime Text 3 for day to day development.

Comment: No third party plugins that work with Eclipse? Was kind of hoping to find a solution inside Eclipse (Something I'm comfortable with)

Comment: Nothing that works with the Force.com IDE. But if you want to contribute, the IDE is open source https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore